# Add custom fileds for Category in admin panel magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, custom, fieldsets

I want to add One custom section in my Magento admin panel for categories. like https://prnt.sc/rf34k5.

And in that section, I want to add 3 text fields like https://prnt.sc/rf34nz.
How can I add custom fields for categories in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Two steps to create the category attribute,

1. Add an **InstallData.php** in the below path

> app/code/vendor/ModuleName/Setup/InstallData.php

then add the below code to it

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
 protected $eav_setup;
 protected $connection;
 public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $connection,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
 ) {
     $this->eav_setup_factory = $eavSetupFactory;
     $this->connection = $connection->getConnection();
     $this->eav_config = $eavConfig;
 }
 public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
 ) {
    $setup->startSetup();

    //create Category Attributes
    $this->createCategoryAttributes($setup);

    $setup->endSetup();
 }
 protected function createCategoryAttributes($setup)
 {
    $eav_setup = $this->eav_setup_factory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eav_setup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'attribute_code',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Category Attribute Name',
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'sort_order' => 420,
            'source' => '',
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => null,
            'group' => 'Custom Attributes',
            'backend' => ''
        ]
    );
 }
}
```

2. Add **category_form.xml** in the below path to make it visible in admin

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

then add the below code to it

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
  <fieldset name="custom_attribute">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Attributes</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="attribute_code">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Category Attribute Name</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

After doing this run the below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx. I followed this. One thing i wanna ask. Now i installed my module and want to make some changes again. so i need to increase the version in category_form.xml???

Comment: Yes you need to increase version in your module.xml if you have changed in UpgradeSchema or add some new column.Please accept this ans if it worked

Comment: i did changes in InstallData.. What is upgradeData...DO i need to change the file name also?

Comment: are you trying to add new column

Comment: Yes, add one attribute in this  $eavSetup->addAttribute

Comment: Yes,I want to add 3 more text fields. So i need to change both installdata.php and xml file.

Comment: Then create  new UpgradeSchema file in setup folder and create there all attribute .Please follow this guide for more help 
  https://www.envisionecommerce.com/blog/how-to-add-an-extra-column-in-your-existing-magento-2-table/

Comment: Don't forget to update version in your module.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105473/discussion-between-nafisa-and-vikas-kalal).

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to first override `view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml` in your custom module.

Inside your `category_form.xml` you have to add your code.

You can create section using below code `(<fieldset></fieldset>)`.

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="custom_setting">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <label translate="true">Custom Setting</label>
        </settings>        
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And you can create field using below code (you have to add this code inside )

```
<field name="category_thumbnail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Icon</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add a UpgradeData.php in the below path

```
/app/code/<Vendor_name>/<Module_name>/Setup/UpgradeData.php
```

Add below code of category attributes

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2020 Devi mage. All rights reserved.
*/

namespace Devi\Mage\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Category setup factory
     *
     * @var CategorySetupFactory
     */
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.1.0') < 0) {
            // set new resource model paths
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup $categorySetup */

            $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
            $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

            $menu_attributes = [
                'sw_ocat_category_font_icon' => [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Font Icon Class',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 30,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'Onepage Category',
                    'note' => 'If this category has no "Icon Image", font icon will be shown. example to input: icon-dollar'
                ],
                'sw_ocat_category_hoverbgcolor' => [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Category Hover Background Color',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 40,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'Onepage Category'
                ],
                'sw_ocat_additional_content' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Additional Content',
                    'input' => 'textarea',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 50,
                    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'Onepage Category'
                ]
            ];

            foreach($menu_attributes as $item => $data) {
                $categorySetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, $item, $data);
            }

            $idg =  $categorySetup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'Onepage Category');

            foreach($menu_attributes as $item => $data) {
                $categorySetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                    $entityTypeId,
                    $attributeSetId,
                    $idg,
                    $item,
                    $data['sort_order']
                );
            }
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Then add category form using UI Component below path

```
/app/code/<Vendor_name>/<Module_name>/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2020 Devi Mage.
 *
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="onepage_category">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Onepage Category</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="sw_ocat_hide_this_item">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Hide This Category</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="sw_ocat_category_font_icon">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Font Icon Class</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="sw_ocat_category_hoverbgcolor">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Hover Background Color</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="sw_ocat_additional_content">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Additional Content</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">3</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Hope this helps you.